# Unable to run Node Js App on Cpanel its showing code instead

Tags: node.js, deployment, cpanel

I have deployed a NodeJs project on cpanel. I have created a subdomain and connected to the relevant code folder. The problem is , i am able to the code of index.js file on the url but unable to run apis.

It is showing something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not running a NodeJS application to serve the code to the web browser, and it is being treated as a regular javascript file by the web service. Thus, the code is shown directly instead of the compiled HTML version. Make sure that you have deployed your app through the "Setup NodeJS App" feature inside your cPanel. If your hosting provider does lack this, I would definitely recommend switching your web host to a more suitable one for NodeJS apps.